# Serving XHTML as application/xhtml+xml with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xhtml, content-type, content-negotiation

I'm trying to get my Rails app to serve XHTML content properly, with the correct content-type of application/xhtml+xml. Ideally with content negotiation so that IE users get a chance to use the site too.

Given that all the HTML generated by Rails is marked at XHTML 1.0 Transitional, I'm a bit surprised that there is no obvious option to make Rails serve markup as XHTML. I found this http://blog.codahale.com/2006/05/23/rails-plugin-xhtml_content_type/, but it seems to be for 1.1.2 and I can't get it working properly under 2.3.8.

Have I missed something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've got something that works now. Thanks to @danivovich for starting me in the right place. The first thing I had to do was sort out the Mime types in mime_types.rb so that HTML wasn't aliased with XHTML:

```
module Mime
  remove_const('HTML') # remove this so that we can re-register the types
end

Mime::Type.register "text/html", :html
Mime::Type.register "application/xhtml+xml", :xhtml
```

The I just added this to my application controller:

```
  before_filter :negotiate_xhtml
  after_filter :set_content_type

  def negotiate_xhtml
    @serving_polyglot = false
    if params[:format].nil? or request.format == :html
      @serving_polyglot = ((not request.accepts.include? :xhtml) or params[:format] == 'html')
      request.format = :xhtml
    end
  end

  def set_content_type
    if @serving_polyglot
      response.content_type = 'text/html'
    end
  end
```

This makes sure that XHTML is always servered as such, unless the client doesn't accept it, or HTML has been explicitly requested. HTML is always just XHTML served as a polyglot. The @serving_polyglot variable is available in the views where any switching is needed.

This is working for me under Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera and IE[6-8].

Answer (score 1):

You can force the content type in any controller function or using an after filter.  Either of these methods can set the content type via:

```
response.content_type = "application/xhtml+xml"
```

Comment: Thanks, this has put me on the right track, but Rails aliases "text/html" with "application/xhtml+xml" (why?) so am having trouble finding out whether the client has sent the XHTML in the accept header. It always gets removed/replaced by the time it gets to my before_filter. What's the best/cleanest way to detect whether the client accepts application/xhtml+xml?

Comment: Fiddler2 for any web traffic, or Firebug for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `application_controller.rb`:

```
 def correct_safari_and_ie_accept_headers
    ajax_request_types = [ 'text/javascript', 'application/json', 'text/xml']
    request.accepts.sort!{ |x, y| ajax_request_types.include?(y.to_s) ? 1 : -1 } if request.xhr?
 end
```

This corrects the safari and ie accept headers so that it defaults to `text/xml` instead of `text/html`. It works for me. Tested both on IE and Safari. Other browsers default to `text/xml` anyways.

**EDIT**: I have set my DOCTYPE to `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">` and not XHTML Transitional.